# In OpenCL, what does mem_fence() do, as opposed to barrier()?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, memory-barriers, barrier, memory-fences

Unlike `barrier()` (which I think I understand), `mem_fence()` does not affect all items in the work group.  The OpenCL spec says (section 6.11.10), for `mem_fence()`:

> Orders loads and stores of a work-item executing a kernel.

(so it applies to a *single* work item).

But, at the same time, in section 3.3.1, it says that:

> Within a work-item memory has load / store consistency.

so *within* a work item the memory is consistent.

So what kind of thing is `mem_fence()` useful for?  It doesn't work across items, yet isn't needed within an item...

Note that I haven't used atomic operations (section 9.5 etc).  Is the idea that `mem_fence()` is used in conjunction with those?  If so, I'd love to see an example.

Thanks.

[The spec, for reference.](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf)

**Update**: I can see how it is useful when used *with* `barrier()` (implicitly, since the barrier calls `mem_fence()`) - but surely there must be more, since it exists separately?

Comment: This presentation provides an example for memory fences: It prevents e. g. a reordering of ````shared_var=value; lock = false;```` (https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/new_lectures/lec3.pdf) For a single isolated work item this reordering would not matter, because for the single work item there seems to be no dependency between these variables => required consistency is given inside the work item. Furthermore this article proved to be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To try to put it more clearly (hopefully),

> `mem_fence()` waits until all reads/writes to local and/or global memory made by the calling work-item prior to mem_fence() are visible to all threads in the work-group.

That comes from: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2009/SIGGRAPH/asia/3_OpenCL_Programming.pdf

Memory operations can be reordered to suit the device they are running on.  The spec states (basically) that any reordering of memory operations must ensure that memory is in a consistent state within a single work-item.  However, what if you (for example) perform a store operation and value decides to live in a work-item specific cache for now until a better time presents itself to write through to local/global memory?  If you try to load from that memory, the work-item that wrote the value has it in its cache, so no problem.  But other work-items within the work-group don't, so they may read the wrong value.  Placing a memory fence ensures that, at the time of the memory fence call, local/global memory (as per the parameters) will be made consistent (any caches will be flushed, and any reordering will take into account that you expect other threads may need to access this data after this point).

I admit it is still confusing, and I won't swear that my understanding is 100% correct, but I think it is at least the general idea.

**Follow Up:**

I found this link which talks about CUDA memory fences, but the same general idea applies to OpenCL:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_Programming_Guide_2.3.pdf

Check out section **B.5 Memory Fence Functions**.

They have a code example that computes the sum of an array of numbers in one call.  The code is set up to compute a partial sum in each work-group.  Then, if there is more summing to do, the code has the last work-group do the work.

So, basically 2 things are done in each work-group: A partial sum, which updates a global variable, then atomic increment of a counter global variable.

After that, if there is any more work left to do, the work-group that incremented the counter to the value of ("work-group size" - 1) is taken to be the last work-group.  That work-group goes on to finish up.

Now, the problem (as they explain it) is that, because of memory re-ordering and/or caching, the counter may get incremented and the last work-group may begin to do its work before that partial sum global variable has had its most recent value written to global memory.

A memory fence will ensure that the value of that partial sum variable is consistent for all threads before moving past the fence.

I hope this makes some sense.  It is confusing.

Comment: but in the example you give, the other thread cannot be sure that the data are stored without a barrier.  so you need the barrier anyway.  i guess i didn't put that in the original question - but i don't see how mem_fence makes sense alone (when not used with a barrier).  sorry if i'm missing something and thanks for the comment...

Comment: I added more detail above.  I hope this helps.

Comment: ok, so the cuda example includes an atomic operation, which is what i was suspecting was necessary for mem_fence to be useful.  for future reference the equivalence between opencl and cuda functions is described here - http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/OpenCL-and-the-AMD-APP-SDK.aspx#four

Comment: While you may be describing the intent of OpenCL men_fence() or inferring from similar CUDA functions, I think the original poster's question remains unanswered.  The OpenCL spec for men_fence(), even now at 1.2, says nothing to suggest it provides consistency among threads in the workgroup. I'm left with the same question, why have men_fence() at all?

Comment: This thread in the AMD forum provides an explanation and example for use that is contradicts this answer.  
http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1242922#1242922

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand it (I'm still trying to verify it)

`memory_fence` will only make sure the memory is consistent and visible to all threads in the group, i.e. the execution does NOT stop, until there is another memory transaction (local or global). Which means if there is a move instruction or an add instruction after a `memory_fence`, the device will continue to execute these "non-memory transaction" instructions.

`barrier` on the other hand will stop execution, period. And will only proceed after all threads reach that point AND all the memory transactions have been cleared.

In other words, `barrier` is a superset of `mem_fence`. `barrier` can prove more expensive in terms of performance than `mem_fence`.

Answer (score 0):

The fence ensures that loads and/or stores issued before the fence will complete before any loads and/or stores issued after the fence. No sinc is implied by the fences alone. The barrier operation supports a read/write fence in one or both memory spaces as well as blocking until all work items in a giver workgroup reach it.